# What does `target` mean in `jsonb_set` of postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I am using `jsonb` type in a column in postgresql11. And I'd like to update one field in the json data and I see there is a function `jsonb_set` which can be used. (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html).

However, based on the document,

> `jsonb_set ( target jsonb, path text[], new_value jsonb [, create_if_missing boolean ] ) → jsonb`
>
> Returns target with the item designated by path replaced by new_value, or with new_value added
> if create_if_missing is true (which is the default) and the item designated by path does not
> exist. All earlier steps in the path must exist, or the target is returned unchanged. As with
> the path oriented operators, negative integers that appear in the path count from the end of
> JSON arrays. If the last path step is an array index that is out of range, and create_if_missing
> is true, the new value is added at the beginning of the array if the index is negative, or at
> the end of the array if it is positive.

The first argument is `target`. What does `target` mean here? Do I need to do a query to get existing value and put it as `target`?

I have tried below update statement:

my current data is:

```
# select "taxes" from "Sites" where "id" = '6daa9b5d-d5b2-4b0d-a8ee-5ad2cb141594';
                                               taxes
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"feePercent": 0, "percent": 0}
```

And I tried below update:

```
# update "Sites" set "feePercent" = jsonb_set('{"feePercent": 0, "percent": 0}', '{feePercent}', 1) where "siteUuid"='6daa9b5d-d5b2-4b0d-a8ee-5ad2cb141594';
```

but I got below error:

```
ERROR:  function jsonb_set(unknown, unknown, integer) does not exist
LINE 1: update "Sites" set "feePercent" = jsonb_set('{"feePerce...
```

Comment: You need a cast: `jsonb_set('{"feePercent": 0, "percent": 0}'::jsonb, ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jsonb_set()` modifies a specific JSON object. So, your target is the JSON object (or JSON column) which you want to modify.

```
jsonb_set(my_jsonb_to_be_modified, ...)
```

So, if you had this JSON object;

```
{"my":"old", "json":"object"}
```

With the function you can turn it into:

```
{"my":"new", "json":"object"}
```

The code is:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=40b90fff7aa616479f5dc5112ecc490c)

```
SELECT jsonb_set('{"my":"old", "json":"object"}', '{my}', '"new"')
```

The `target` is the original JSON object, the `path` points to the element you want to modify, and `new_value` is the new value for the element you specified in the path.

In that case my had the value `old`, which turns into `new` now.

Comment: what value should I put in `my_jsonb_to_be_modified`? The `jsonb_set` function already has `new_value` as the third parameter.

Comment: Extended the answer

Comment: Does this mean I need to do a query before update? Also why do you put `jsonb_set` after `SELECT`?

Comment: I have updated my question with your approach but got some error

Comment: Removing the " characters from the path should do the trick. path is a text array, not a json array. So " characters are not required.

Comment: I update my question. I got the same error after removing double quote

Comment: SELECT jsonb_set('{"feePercent": 0, "percent": 0}', '{feePercent}', '1')   https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=3efaea6aa090da84e7970f0eed3a8885

Comment: SELECT is just to show the result of the function call. Of course you need to transform it to your update: UPDATE mytable SET mycolumn = jsonb_set('{"feePercent": 0, "percent": 0}', '{feePercent}', '1')

Comment: ok, it works. seems that I need to quote the integer value.

Comment: the function is named jsonb_set and not jsonb ;)

Comment: so that means I have to do a query before update?

Comment: No: UPDATE mytable SET mycolumn = jsonb_set('{"feePercent": 0, "percent": 0}', '{feePercent}', '1')

Comment: I have tried that `update`, `percent` will become 0. That means the target object is very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

From PostgreSQL v14 on, you can use subscripts to make this `UPDATE` statement look natural:

```
UPDATE "Sites"
SET taxes['feePercent'] = to_jsonb(1)
WHERE id = '6daa9b5d-d5b2-4b0d-a8ee-5ad2cb141594';
```

For earlier versions, you will have to use `jsonb_set` like this:

```
UPDATE "Sites"
SET taxes = jsonb_set(taxes, ARRAY['feePercent'], to_jsonb(1))
WHERE id = '6daa9b5d-d5b2-4b0d-a8ee-5ad2cb141594';
```

The effect is the same: the whole JSON is read, a new JSON is created and stored in a new version of the row.

All this becomes much simpler if you don't use JSON, but regular table columns.